# Texture Atlas script for single mesh with multiple materials?

Tags: mesh, scripting, uv, texture-baking

I am new to Blender. I mainly use it for editing simple models for my own engine.
I want to keep the number of draw calls low. So, every time In do the following:

1. I merge all meshes into one that has, say, 4 materials.
2. I create an empty 5th material.
3. I create a second UV map called Atlas.
4. I unwrap all faces using smart unwrap to that UV map.
5. I create an empty texture and name it Atlas.
6. For each material (except for the Atlas one) I create a new image texture node in shading mode, connect it to the Atlas UV map and choose my Atlas texture as source. This texture node is the only selected node.
7. I switch to cycles render and bake the diffuse channel.

Now, is there anyone out there who has a script for that? There must be a better or quicker way!

For 50+ models, this can become very annoying...

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: Nevermind, found a good solution: https://github.com/Grim-es/material-combiner-addon

Comment: don't be afraid to answer your own question and accept the answer :)
btw. thy that was exactly wat i was searching for.